# Using arsort inside a class

Tags: php, arrays

**Okay so here is the thing. Im using PHPStorm. with stepping through the code is appeard NOT sorted in the debugger. However, when I did a var_dump it DID sort.  so this question is invalid as PHPStorm is at fault possibly.**

Im trying to sort an associative array within a class.
This is what I tried, but it does not sort anything. It remains the same.

```
arsort($returnArray,SORT_NUMERIC);
```

So I though I might try something like what they use in `usort`

```
arsort($returnArray[$soa], array('App\Services\ReportsService','merchantSort'));

private static function merchantSort($a,$b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

But this gives me

> arsort() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given

Why is the `arsort` not working as expected and how should I do it?

snip of the array that I want to sort by value and retain the keys.

```
$returnArray = array("Ward 1"=>35, "Ward 9"=>37, "Ward 3"=>43, "Ward 6"=>41, "Ward 4"=>4);
```

Comment: arsort : http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php needs the second parameter to be a flag.

Comment: But look at my first example code, that did not do/sort anything.

Comment: We don't read tea leaves here. Print the `$returnArray` first. Also please explain what result you are trying to achieve. Reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help.

Comment: [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) may be the function you are looking for

Comment: Couldn't you give us a minimal viable example in code? You won't expect us to write an array based on your image, will you?

Comment: It's really hard to help you. Your reputation is high though you don't know how to ask properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [`asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

```
$returnArray = array(
    "Ward 1"=>35, 
    "Ward 9"=>37, 
    "Ward 3"=>43, 
    "Ward 6"=>41, 
    "Ward 4"=>4
);

asort($returnArray, SORT_NUMERIC);

print_r($returnArray);
```

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [Ward 4] => 4
>     [Ward 1] => 35
>     [Ward 9] => 37
>     [Ward 6] => 41
>     [Ward 3] => 43
> )
> ```

Note: the asort function changes the original array. If you don't want that, you have to clone your array before.

See here for a sandbox
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db5f4a3842c5594d2d5830985a7b9c417cf81703

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4);
usort($array, array('Namespace\Of\Your\ClassName','functionName'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your input array is an associative array. My guess is you want to sort the values inside.

Entire array:

```
foreach ($inputArray as &$innerArray) {
    arsort($innerArray, SORT_NUMERIC);
}
```

Particular item:

```
arsort($inputArray[2], SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Example:

```
<pre>
<?php

$i = ['Ward 2' => 10, 'Ward 1' => 76];

echo 'Sorting by key descending:';
krsort($i, SORT_STRING);
print_r($i);

echo 'Sorting by value descending:';
arsort($i, SORT_STRING);
print_r($i);

?>
</pre>
```

Comment: I tried the Particular item sort. does not give an error, but does not sort it... why could this be?

Comment: Because it works on integers and your array contains strings.

Comment: Alas... using `arsort($returnArray[$soa],SORT_STRING );`still has no effect.

Comment: Did you read in the [documentation](http://php.net/sort) how `SORT_STRING` works? ;) Please read my comments. Include input array and desired output array in your question. Help us help you finally please.

Comment: Okay so here is the thing. Im using PHPStorm. with stepping through the code is appeard NOT sorted in the debugger. However, when I did a var_dump it DID sort.  so this question is invalid as PHPStorm is at fault possibly.

Comment: Thanks for your time anyways!